# Geometry: polar equation of conics

Tags: experimental-mathematics

In finding polar equations of conics we take focus as the origin but ellipse has 2 focci so which focus is taken as the origin?
Or
If if focus is not taken on origin then how to find the polar equation of ellipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simplest polar equation for the ellipse, take one focus at the origin and the second focus as $r=b,\theta=0$ with$b>0$.  Thus the second focus would lie along the positive $x$ axis in rectangular coordinates or the ray $\theta=0$ in polar coordinates.

Let $O$ be the origin, $A$ be the second focus at $r=b>0,\theta=0$ and $P$ be a point on the ellipse.  Defining $e$ as the eccentricity of the ellipse we then have from the Law of Cosines on $\triangle OAP$:

$|AP|^2=|OA|^2+|OP|^2-2|OA||OP|\cos \theta$

$((b/e)-r)^2=b^2+r^2-2br\cos \theta$

We expand the left side and note that the quadratic terms in $r$ cancel out leading to an equation that is linear in $r$:

$(b/e)^2-b^2=2br((1/e)-\cos \theta)$

Solving for $r$:

$r=\frac{b(1-e^2)/2e}{1-e \cos \theta}=\frac{a}{1-e \cos \theta}$

where $a$ is the [semilatus rectum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LatusRectum.html) of the ellipse.

Comment: +1. It may be worth noting that the "simplest" equation is actually a tie: $$r = \frac{a}{1-e\cos\theta}\qquad\text{vs}\qquad r=\frac{a}{1+e\cos\theta}$$ Both have a focus at the origin. As you mention, the first has its other focus on the positive $x$-axis; the second has it on the negative $x$-axis. I prefer the latter, so that, as $e$ approaches $1$ and the conic approaches a parabola, the figure gets wider off to the left, while the behavior at $\theta=0$ (the traditional "start" of an angular sweep) remains comparatively steady. (That steadiness persists for hyperbolic sweeps with $e>1$.)

Comment: How to trace the conic by this equation?

Comment: Also, readers should be aware that your use of $a$ and $b$ (and thus also my use in the above comment) is different than is typically used to describe ellipses.

Comment: @blue I know the nomenclature is different.  But the form I first saw used $a$ as the semilatus rectum leading me down the garden path.